# mysql 8 using a wildcard in query when selecting a date

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently using this query:

```
General error: 1525 Incorrect DATE value: '2020-02%'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT
                    '01',
                    2103,
                    cssd._campaign_id,
                    cssd.first,
                    cssd.last,
                    cssd.street,
                    cssd.city,
                    cssd.state,
                    cssd.zip,
                    cssd.customer_id,
                    cssd.vin,
                    cssd.email,
                    cssd.phone,
                    cssd.phone2,
                    cssd.phonecell
                    FROM combined_sales_service_data cssd
                    WHERE cssd._campaign_id = 25
                    AND cssd.last_date >= '2020-02%'
```

last_date is a DATE field.

Which used to work in 5.7, however in 8.0 i'm getting the date error above.

Now I can update the date to 2020-02-01 but I would like to be able to use the wildcard in some situations.

Is there a better way to formulate this statement without setting the ALLOW_INVALID_DATES

Thanks

Comment: You really can't compare a date with a wildcard as a less than/greater than. Pick a specific date in February (such as Feb 1st).

Comment: `%` is a wildcard only if you use it with the operator `LIKE`. Your query worked coincidentally because the character `'%'` is considered less than the character `'-'` which follows the month in a Date value. Don't use it. Use proper date comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

there are many option but you can make something like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (last_date date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('2022-02-01'), ('2022-03-01'),('2022-01-01'),('2021-01-01'),('2023-01-01')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm table1
> WHERE DATE_FORMAT(last_date ,'%Y-%m') >= '2022-02'
> ```
>
> ```
> | last_date  |
> | :--------- |
> | 2022-02-01 |
> | 2022-03-01 |
> | 2023-01-01 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79b4b62d6f294c867ce66ba0d4c7619e)*